# Не отображается только кириллическая буква "а". Остальные - в порядке

Tags: python, utf-8, unicode, python-2.x, selenium-webdriver

Используя *selenium webdriver*, пытаюсь ввести текст в поле на странице.

Проблема в том, что вся кириллица работает нормально, кроме буквы «а».
Например текст: "Спасибо парни" в поле выглядит "Спсбо прни".

В начале файла указано:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Текст получаю:

```
text = raw_input('Введите текст...')
dectxt = text.decode('utf8')
```

Пытаюсь вывести

```
fld = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='locationsearchBar']/.../input")
fld.send_keys(dectxt)
```

И буква потеряна. Как это исправить?

Comment: В строке "Введите текст..." нет ни одной буквы "а".

Comment: Эта строка тут и ни при чем. ...Изначально raw_input() присваивают какой либо переменной, а затем в скобках пишется текст, который выводится на экран перед вводом....  Проблема в введеном через терминал тексте.

Comment: Понял. Вы не указали в вопросе, что вводите данные с клавиатуры. Ок, тогда вопрос немного не по теме: а зачем в автоматизированном тесте что-то вводить с клавиатуры? Почему нельзя просто `dectxt='blablabla'`? У вас получается автотест, в котором каждый раз надо что-то делать руками и это ломает всю идею.

Comment: (в питоне не разбираюсь на должном уровне, уж извините).

Comment: Selenium WebDriver  использую не для автоматизированного теста.

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` влияет только на буквы, которые явно в исходном коде присутствуют, то есть декларация влияет на `'Введите текст...'` (кстати, нужно `u''` использовать, иначе кракозябы получатся если терминал не `utf-8`), но она никак не влияет на `text`, то есть `text.decode('utf-8')` может сломаться тоже (в качестве полумеры можно `.decode(sys.stdin.encoding or locale.getpreferredencoding(False))` попробовать). Чтобы понять, что с буквой `'а'`, создайте минимальный самодостаточный пример кода (например, убрать `raw_input()` и использовать константу `repr(text)`).

Comment: Кодировка html формы -- это уже третья кодировка. Нужно посмотреть, что по сети браузеру посылается.